Axler's Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra
I'm working through Linear Algebra Done Right, 4e and I don't understand a step in the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. He has shown that for polynomial $p$, the real-valued function $|p(z)|$ has a global minimum at some $\zeta$, and proceeds to show that $|p(\zeta)|  = 0$ by contradiction. He writes:
Define a new polynomial $q$ by
$q(z) = \dfrac{p(z + \zeta)}{p(\zeta)}$
The function $z \rightarrow |q(z)|$ has a global minimum value of $1$ at $z = 0$. Write
$q(z) = 1 + a_kz^k + \ldots + a_mz^m,$
where $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that the coefficient of $z^k$ is nonzero. Let  $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $\beta^k = -\dfrac{1}{a_k}$. There is a constant $c >1 $ such that if $t \in (0, 1)$, then
$ |q(t\beta)| \leq |1 + a_kt^k\beta^k| + t^{k+1}c
 = 1 - t^k(1 - tc)$
I have no idea where he's getting that last bound from. What is $c?$ Why is $t \in (0, 1)$ only? Why do we only have two terms $t^k$ and $t^{k+1}$? Why did the absolute value disappear? What is the motivation for considering this term in the first place? He's completely lost me.
Edit: furthermore, he writes:
Thus taking $t$ to be $1/(2c)$ in the inequality above, we have $|q(t\beta)| < 1$.
How do we know that $t$ chosen in this way is in $(0, 1)$?

There exists such a $c$ because $\{a_{k+1}\beta^{k+1}+ta_{k+2}\beta^{k+2}+\dots+t^{m-k-1}a_m\beta^m\mid0<t<1\}$ is bounded.
We consider only small positive values of $t$, to use only the fact that we have a local minimum.
The absolute value disappeared because $1+a_kt^k\beta^k=1-t^k>0$.
$1/(2c)\in(0,1)$ because $c>1>1/2$.
These choices were done to produce a contradiction.

I don't see why $c > 1$ necessarily. Also, why are we able to pull out only a $t^{k+1}$ term?

$c>1$ is not necessarily but feasible. It is an arbitrary additional constraint, in order for $1/(2c)$ to belong to $(0,1)$. Note that $c>1/2$ would be sufficient. We are not pulling out only $a_{k+1}t^{k+1}$ but all the terms of degree $\ge k+1$: look at the set in the 1st sentence of my answer.
